# Proving $(ab)^{1/n}=a^{1/n}b^{1/n}$.

Tags: proof-explanation, exponentiation

In this book: Lang, Serge. "Basic Mathematics" (p. 71), appears this theorem and proof.

**Theorem 1.** Let $a$, $b$ be positive real numbers. Then,
$$(ab)^{1/n}=a^{1/n}b^{1/n}$$

*Proof.* Let $r=a^{1/n}$ and $s=b^{1/n}$. This means that $r^n=a$ and $s^n=b$.
Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
(rs)^n
=r^ns^n 
= ab
\end{align}
$$

- How does the author came up with the equality $(rs)^n
  =r^ns^n$ ? 
  That exponent property wasn't introduced in the book at this point.

Comment: Commutativity on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $n$ is a natural?

Comment: Thanks for the question. $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: @Phicar, product rule wasn't introduced at this point; why do you say Commutativity ?

Comment: @Phicar, in some places, it is called product rule to $(ab)^n=a^n b^n$. It appears one or two pages later in the book.

Comment: @F.Zer Page 62. The author states $a\cdot b=b\cdot a.$ Is induction allowed?

Comment: @Phicar, thanks. That's the page where commutativity rule appears. Induction is not allowed at this point.

Comment: @F.Zer So no proof i can give you. Check page 19. the author assumes you can do this things, then take a look at Saaqib's answer.

Comment: @Phicar, you are right, in p. 19 appears product rule numbered **N12**. The problem is, in page 71 appears **Theorem 1**. Below, on that same page, he says that we shall assume without proof the following property of numbers: Fractional powers. The third one is POW 3 ($(ab)^n=a^n b^n$). I wonder why he is using something in the proof to state it later. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is a positive integer and $r$ and $s$ are any positive real numbers, then we find that
$$
\begin{align}
(rs)^n &= \underbrace{(rs) \times \cdots \times (rs)}_{n \mbox{ times} } \\
&= \left( \underbrace{ r \times \cdots \times r}_{n \mbox{ times} } \right) \times \left( \underbrace{ s \times \cdots \times s}_{n \mbox{ times} } \right) \\
&= r^n \times s^n.
\end{align}
$$
Here we have used the commutative property of multiplication.

Alternatively, we can prove 
$$
(rs)^n = r^n s^n
$$
for all positive real numbers $r$ and $s$ and for all natural numbers $n$ using induction on $n$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, @Saaqib Mahmood. As I said in one of the comments, I am not sure I can use that proof as, below the page, the author states it without proof. He names it **POW 3**.